# jQuery Div OnClick trigger sibling link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, siblings

How would I make `<div class="hover"></div>` on click trigger `<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">`? I've tried using the sibling selector and I can't seem to get the hang of it..

When somebody clicks on div.hover I need a new window to open using the href of the sibling anchor.

```
<ul id="photoUL">
<li>
<div class="hover"></div>
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">
<img width="150" height="150" style="border: 1px solid #000000;" title="2013 Dirty Duathlon" src="http://example.com/example.jpg">
</a>
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">EXAMPLE</a>
</li>
```

Comment: what do you want? please explain and post your js code.

Comment: Triggering a click won't trigger the anchor's native behavior!

Comment: are you trying to change page url to example.com ?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui I have explained; When clicking on div.hover I need to open the href of the sibling link

Answer (score 5):

```
$('div.hover').on('click',function(){
    window.location.href = $(this).next('a').attr('href');
});
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/NGwL9/

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kuJPC/

This will open `http://example.com` in a new tab when `.hover` is clicked which will have the same behavior as `<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">`

```
$('.hover').click(function() {
  window.open('http://example.com','_newtab');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use "window.open", you can put a click handler on the hover and use the next function to simulate the click of the next anchor tag.

```
$('.hover').click(function(){
    $(this).next('a')[0].click();
});
```

Here is a working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4FNJM/1/